# Different routing for two different controllers

Tags: cakephp, controller, routes

I have two different controller, 
AdminController.php and 
HomeController.php

I want add routing for HomeController.php functions only. I added the Router::connect() function for HomeContrller.php functions and it is working fine. 
But my AdminController.php is not working properly now :(.

My question is, if we have two controller and I want to add routing only for one controller function. How can we do it?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php just specify the controller and the action. Ex:

```
Router::connect('/profile/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
//the * means anything after the slash....www.example.com/profile/123
```